# i'm trying to share localhost with ngrok

Tags: laravel, localhost, share, ngrok

i'm trying to access my localhost via ngrok, and my project is Laravel 5.3

The connection to http://****.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:8000.

how can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly check if you tunnel same port which is used by your application like 8000.